# How do I print an Emoji as the text of a button?

Tags: java

I have tried hexadecimal values for the emoji in the text field but it did not work. I'm new to android studio . Do I need to code it in? Or can I add it to the layout? Or both? Thank you

Comment: Try by inserting directly the emoji to your code.

`System.out.println("Hello world ");`

Comment: It worked!  Thank you!!!

Comment: This emoji is part of `UTF-8` and Java can read that right from the source file. For other stuff you would need to specify the encoding of the emoji before reading the corresponding bytes.

Answer (score 1):

As we found out in the comments, the solution would be to put the code directly into the Java source e.g:

```
System.out.println("Hello world ");
```

Or the XML source:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
    android:text="" />
```